# async wordpress thumbnails generations only after save post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I have a wordpress site with woocommerce, each product has many images (10-15) and each original image is 1-2 MB. these dimensions are necessary for the purposes of the sector of this site.

Every time I create a product it takes a long time (more than 60 seconds) after the images are loaded and this is due to the fact that thumbails are generated for each image.

My idea was to disable thumbnail generation and run the regeneration in the background after the post is saved. This way I don't have to wait for thumbnails to be generated for each post.

I believe this request can be useful to many other people who may find themselves in a similar case.

my idea was to activate the regeneration of the images after 5 seconds or immediately after completing the saving of the post, I created this code but on the first try it doesn't seem to work:

```
// Schedule thumbnail generation after post save
function schedule_thumbnail_generation($post_id) {
    // Set the time interval (5 seconds in our case)
    $delay_seconds = 5;

    // Calculate the timestamp for the future thumbnail generation event
    $timestamp = time() + $delay_seconds;

    // Schedule the event using WP-Cron
    wp_schedule_single_event($timestamp, 'generate_thumbnail_event', array($post_id));
}

add_action('save_post', 'schedule_thumbnail_generation');

// Disable automatic thumbnail generation
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'disable_thumbnail_generation');

function disable_thumbnail_generation($sizes) {
    return array();
}

// Callback function for thumbnail generation
function generate_thumbnail_callback($post_id) {
    // Get all attachments for the post
    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
    ));

    // Loop through attachments and generate thumbnails
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $attachment_id = $attachment->ID;

        // Generate thumbnails for the attachment
        $attachment_metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, get_attached_file($attachment_id));

        // Update the attachment metadata with the newly generated thumbnails
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_metadata);
    }
}

add_action('generate_thumbnail_event', 'generate_thumbnail_callback');
```

**UPDATE:** Solved with adding this code in generate_thumbnail_callback function:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. What is the problem?

Comment: Hi @AlexHowansky, the problem is the code not works